# Should I change React Native UI updates based on state or based on database information?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When the user first opens the application, it is listed according to the information in the local database. Flatlist has button items. These buttons are shown in red or blue color according to the information in the database.

When the user touches any button, the color information in the database changes.

Now, should I change this change in the UI part with state on a component basis, or should I query the database and update the flatlist information after saving the new information to the database?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should make the state and the database synchronous :

```js
useEffect(() => {
 // API call then update your state based on data returned from your database
})
```

If the API call you are using to update your database is returning updated data then ech time you make an API call you get advantage of the response to update your state this will trigger a render and the UI will be updated as well

However if your endpoint only updates the database, better is to make it also returning the updated data as response, and if you don't want to do that then you should make two requests, PATCH/PUT then GET

Comment: The database I am using returns the new data after updating the data. I can update the flatlist with this data. But I'm not sure if this performs? The second solution is to change only the state of the item's component. Wouldn't that be more performant? I don't know which one to choose on this one.

Comment: What I want to say is that when the user makes a change, update the database and update the state of the component according to the change. I think this will be more performant. Otherwise, when the user makes changes, it will save it to the database, then wait for the return and the flatlist will be fully updated. That sounds a bit underperforming.??

Comment: the first solution you mentioned looks more performant and a good idea but it fact it is NOT, the API call may not success in some cases that's why you should wait for the response to make sure the db is updated then update the stae  otherwise you risk to have state updated but not the database

Comment: how bout adding one submit button to submit all the selected rows, so only 1 time request to submit all once for all, updating each row every time user click and checking, to much time consuming..

Comment: @bagi2info.com You are right, but this is an example scenario. Unfortunately in the real app experience the user will not want a second button for this.

Comment: does the solution above helped ?